# How can I see the value of randInt(0,18), what do they mean by that description?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to understand the description of "Mobs that spawn with enchanted equipment have higher levels of enchantments.". But which level are they talking about, what is the percentage chance of getting higher enchantment and how can I see the value of randInt(0,18) ?
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Difficulty#Other_effects

[image: Mobs that spawn with enchanted equipment have higher levels of enchantments.]

Comment: You want to inspect the RAM of a running process? Most operating systems have strong limitations on that for security reasons.

Comment: randInt generates a pseudo-random integer, with a (hopefully) uniform distribution, so you can assume that each number in 0-17 interval has the same chance to came out.

Comment: @FabianRöling Wait what ?

Comment: @pinckerman Yes, but how can I see the value ?

Comment: Ideally you can't, that would be a security issue in the operating system. Why do you want to, though? It's just an intermediate step in a calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since *BambooleanLogic*'s answer covers the enchantment level generation, this is what enchantment level does, according to [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting_mechanics#How_enchantments_are_chosen).

#### Step one – Applying modifiers to the enchantment level

The first thing that Minecraft does is apply two modifiers to the base enchantment level. Each modifier is restricted to a certain range, with numbers close to the middle of the range more common than those near the ends.

The first modifier is based on the item's "enchantability," which depends on the material and the type of the item ([see the table](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting_mechanics#Enchantability)). Minecraft picks a number between 0 and half the enchantability, then adds that number plus one to the enchantment level.

#### Step two – Find possible enchantments

Now, based on the modified level, Minecraft makes a list of all enchantment types that can be applied to the target item along with the power that each enchantment has.

The power of each enchantment type is determined by the level and the values in the [enchantments levels table](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting/Levels). For each power value of an enchantment type, there is a minimum and maximum modified level that can produce the enchantment at that power. If the modified enchantment level (calculated at the first step) is within the range of an enchantment's possible power values, then the enchantment is assigned the modified enchantment level as power. If the modified level is within two overlapping ranges for the same enchantment type, the higher power value is used.

Some enchantments are "treasure enchantments", meaning they can never be created by an enchanting table.

#### Step three – Select a set of enchantments from the list

Now that it has a list of the possible enchantments for the item, Minecraft must pick some of them to apply. Each enchantment has a statistical "weight" ([see the table](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting_mechanics#Step_three_%E2%80%93_Select_a_set_of_enchantments_from_the_list)). Enchantments with higher weights have a higher chance of being selected.
The player always gets at least one enchantment on an item, and there is a chance of receiving more.

Comment: Is this the same thing with that a random spawned mob's armor, not only enchantment table ? Like a random zombie has been spawned with an enchanted boots (Frost Walker I)

Comment: I feel that they work pretty much the same, but I'm not sure if mob can spawn with treasure enchanted gears

Answer (score 2):

There is no "one" value of `randInt(0,18)`, it is a *random value* between 0 and 17 that gets rerolled every time the game needs to choose an enchantment level.

Assuming for the sake of simplicity that the current CRD is 1.0, that means that the level can be between 5 + (0 * 1.0) and 5 + (17 * 1.0). In other words, the range of possible levels is between 5 and 22. Which one is it? *It varies for each piece of equipment.* A new random value is chosen between 5 and 22 each time the game needs to spawn a new piece of enchanted mob equipment.

For lower CRD values, the upper limit will be lower, down to a minimum of 5.

(Edit: The wiki page appears to be unclear whether a level is chosen for each piece of enchanted mob equipment, or just once per mob with enchanted equipment which then applies to all its equipment. Still, the point is that `randInt(0,18)` is a value that's constantly different from one moment of time to another.)

Comment: Thank you very much for that! The enchantment level you are talking about is that? [image link](https://i.hizliresim.com/dugcult.jpg)

Comment: I don't know exactly how the randomly selected enchantment level correlates to the exact enchantments chosen (and which level between I-V it becomes), but "probably something like that".

Comment: For an example, the CRD is 0.22. The random number is 9. So, the formula is 5 + (9 * 0.22) and it's result is 6.98. So, the enchantment level is 6.98, right ?

Comment: Values are rounded to the nearest integer, according to the wiki, so for your example the final value will be 7

Comment: @pinckerman, thanks! But then what happens when the value 7 is chosen ?